# Pool or billiards in 1890s American South?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, american-english, history

Which term is more likely to have been used in Georgia around 1893? I found a British website which explains the origin of the modern game known as American pool (http://www.tradgames.org.uk/games/Pool.htm.) They say that all the predecessor of all modern "pocket billiards" games was American fifteen-ball pool or "sixty-one pool." They also say that "continuous" pool (the same as fifteen-ball pool but with a different scoring system) replaced fifteen-ball pool as the championship game in 1888. What I am not sure of, however, is if the generic term for these games was "billiards," "pool," or something else in the 1890s American South.

Comment: I don’t really think ELU is the best way for you to research source material for your own personal creative writing project like this.  How many of these near-identical questions have you asked now?

Comment: I've asked a lot of these types of questions because it's hard to find answers elsewhere. I've actually found most people on here to be very helpful so far. Also, I've noticed that several of my questions have been viewed by more than a few people. Maybe they're helpful and educational for others as well as myself.

Comment: This type of question is fine, *provided that you first do your own research and include the results in the question before asking for expert help.*

Comment: +1 Good Q, but as MετάEd said. Edit the post to include your findings so far. Not voting to close, yet.

Comment: This term [pocket billiards](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pocket%20billiards). I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: [Pocket Billiards](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pocket%2Bbilliards?q=pocket+billiards) @BrianHooper. Or was that a joke?

Comment: @MattЭллен, all the dictionaries I have checked include that definition, and never once have I heard the term used to mean anything other than the Urban Dictionary version.

Comment: Ditto what tchrist and MετάEd said; I get the feeling that I did more legwork before commenting than you do before posting your questions.  Re your comment, while others may be interested, one reason for views is simply that you post a lot of questions and never accept an answer - so people looking for questions to answer find yours.  Anyway, now you've gotten several good answers that include what sound like good resources - next time, please check those first.  Honestly, it sounds like you should spend some time going through those anyway, so you have a better feel for your material.

Comment: Also, mark questions as answered when they are.   Also, continuing the 'meta-tangent' ... Why are you writing this?   Why this setting?   Have you done any research on it?

Comment: I'm new to this site and didn't know I needed to mark questions as answered; pardon my ignorance, but I still don't know how. Yes, I have done research and I plan to do more. I had researched everything I asked on this site before posting my questions but didn't provide what I had found. I see now that I should have. But honestly, I'm seeing that this site is not the best place for me to look for answers right now. I'd also prefer to keep my reasons for writing to myself at this point. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @tchrist - so, what happens in this situation?   How do we close these / mark as answered?   (Given that they seem to be answered, and the poster can't be bothered to mark them as such.)

Answer (score 1):

The South is a pretty big place, but—at least in Virginia in the 1890s—billiards, pocket billiards, and pool were all commonly enough played (and gambled on) to draw the baleful eye of the state legislature. Here is the first half of section 2835 of chapter 228 of the state code of Virginia "relating to dealings with students and gaming" (approved February 8, 1898):

> **What dealings with students prohibited.**—If any money be lent or advanced, or anything sold or let to him, *or for playing billiards, pocket billiards, pool, and bagatelle* on credit to or for the use of any student or pupil under twenty-one years of age at the University of Virginia, Virginia military institute, or any incorporated college in this state, without the previous permission in writing of his parent or guardian or the authorized officers of such institution, nothing shall be recovered therefor, and there shall, moreover, be forfeited to the institution twenty dollars, and the amount or value of such money or other thing. [[emphasis in original]]

I wonder how frequently the authorized officers of the University of Virginia gave prior written permission to students to borrow money to play billiards with.